# How can I pass a list of TextSpan to a function in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a list of TextSpan that I have initialize to an empty list and later I add TextSpan to it if a certain condition is met.

`List<TextSpan> _textSpan = [];`

```
if(text.contains("*")){
  _textSpan.add(TextSpan( text: text), style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.w400))
} else if (){
.
.
.
}
```

Later I return :

```
AutoSizeText.rich(
TextSpan(
children: _textSpan,
Style: TextStyle(),
))
```

My question is How can I create a function that I will be able to wrap `children: _textSpan` to `children: funct(_textSpan)`

I have tried:

```
function(List<TextSpan> StextSpan){
...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this work for You?

```
List<TextSpan> function(List<TextSpan> x){
  //Do what You want to do with x
  return x;
}
```

Then do:
`children: function(_textSpan)`